# Proving an integer sequence is defined by a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, integers

Let's say you have some integer sequence, $a_1, a_2, . . ., a_n$, and you can prove that there exists some $r$ such that the $r$th difference of the sequence is a sequence of just constants. How could we prove that $a_n$ can be defined by some polynomial in $n$?

By $r$th difference I mean you keep on subtracting consecutive terms from each other to form a new sequence. So, the first difference of the sequence $a_n = n^2$ (which is $1$, $4$, $9,$ $16,$ $25,$ $36,...$) would be $3$, $5$, $7,$ $9,$ $11,...$ The second difference of $a_n$ would be $2,$ $2,$ $2,$ $2,...$

Comment: Check out the [method of differences](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/).

Comment: The Brilliant article proves that "If a polynomial $f(x)$ has degree $k$, then the $k$th difference is constant," but it doesn't prove the converse. What's the theorem that shows the converse of the statement is true?

Comment: Did you see how to "reconstruct the polynomial" using a row of the difference table, alongside the proof after it? In particular, $ \begin{array} {r c l l l } f(n) = &  & \frac{D_{d}(1)}{d!} & \times & (x-1)(x-2)\ldots (x-d+1) (x-d) \\
& + & \frac{D_{d-1}(1)}{(d-1)!} & \times & (x-1)(x-2)\ldots (x-d+1 )  \\
& + &  \ldots \\
& + & \frac{D_1(1)}{1!} & \times & (x-1) \\
& + & \frac{D_0 (1)}{0!} & \times & 1 \end{array} $

Comment: Ah I see. Great, thank you so much!

Comment: @eliyablon FYI, using a [site search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=polynomial+method+of+differences), there's [Proof that common differences imply a polynomial-generated sequence](/q/1592605), which I believe deals with your question. There's also other related questions, e.g., [Use the method of finite differences to determine a formula](/q/3367236), [Help with a different approach to extracting a polynomial equation from differences](/q/418840), etc.